# Can't pass div ID to code behind although it has runat=server

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, formview

I have a DIV (id=itemButtons) inside the ItemTemplate of a FormView. Although it has runat=server its ID can¨t be passed to the code behind. I get an error that itemButtons is not declared. Any help?

CODE BEHIND

```
Sub Page_Load() Handles Me.Load
itemButtons.visible = True
End Sub
```

ASPX PAGE

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="IDrecipe" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="itemButtons" visible="false" runat="server">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not accessible because it is in the `ItemTemplate` of the `Formiew`. Only controls which are sitting on top of the page, or better, which `NamigContainer` is the `Page` can be accessed directly via `Id`.

You need to use `FindControl` on it's `NamingContainer` which is the `FormView` that needs to be in the `ReadOnly`-mode because it is in the `ItemTemplate`.

A good place for the code is the  `DataBound` - event:

```
Private Sub FormView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView1.DataBound
    Select Case FormView1.CurrentMode
        Case FormViewMode.ReadOnly
            Dim itemButtons = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("itemButtons"), HtmlGenericControl)
            itemButtons.isible = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

But why don't you use a `Panel` which is rendered as a div if you need to access it on serverside?

Comment: the script works well as long as I am in the ItemTemplate but it throws an error if I change to the other modes (edit and insert).

Comment: But i've already shown an example in the `FormView`' `DataBound`-event using the appropriate `FormViewMode.ReadOnly`. This works always. If you also have this div in the other templates like `Edit`, you need to extend the `Select Case `. You can use the same ID for the controls since they are in different `NamingContainer`s.

Comment: Thanks Tim, yes your code worked well. I've used the Select Case for the other form views....xxxxx